# Did Tim Russ (Tuvok) act in Alongside Night for philosophical or professional reasons (or both)?

Tags: movie, alongside-night

*Alongside Night* is a near future 2014 film adaptation of the book, which promotes views one might describe as capitalist, free market, anti-fiat, libertarian, etc.

The movie definitely had a "low budget" feel to it, so when I saw Tim Russ (who played Tuvok on Star Trek) playing a leading role, accompanied by his assistant who was played by Star Trek castmate Garrett Wang, I was wondering if he/they were really just in the film out of professional reasons, or if they had personal/philosophical interest in it?

Comment: I helped w/ the tags by removing the star-trek and star-trek-voyager tags since the question has nothing to do with those franchises other than the actors :)

Comment: @NKCampbell many thanks. Someone else must have added them (with good intent) but it wasn't  me. I thought about it but I think it needs a new tag for alongside-night instead. I'm still on mobile only though so I can't even see the current tags. The mobile app needs some work IMHO.

Comment: I added a tag - bigger admins than me can kill it if they want :)

Comment: Given the overt political theming (and the refusal of several other actors to play roles in the film) it would have to be political. That being said, neither actor appears to have ever turned down a role, no matter how terrible

Comment: For the record, this might actually be the worst film I've ever seen. The production values are terrible. The editing is dire. The acting is so bad it's only rivalled in its paucity by the script.

Comment: @Valorum I didn't endorse it! Haha did you really go out and watch it? I told you it was low budget.  I watched it because I found out the book was the inspiration for the guy who created the Silk Road and I was just curious. The book was better than the movie for sure tho.

Comment: @Hack-R - I watched about ten minutes. It was dreadful in a way that only the truly sincere can manage; verging on a parody of itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems likely that both actors were very well aware of the film's content and message. According to an interview between The Libertarian Enterprise and the film's writer/director/producer/editor J. Neil Schulman, various actors were approached and **refused to take part because of the overtly libertarian stance.**

> *Now, I will reveal publicly for the first time that **I made offers to
> two prominent Star Trek actors for Alongside Night and was turned down
> because of the libertarian content.** I offered Walter Koenig the role
> of Dr. Murray Konkin and Walter turned me down because I had not
> written this libertarian revolutionary as a villain and I refused to
> rewrite the role to make him one. Walter even admitted that if my
> story had been set in the further future on another planet he wouldn't
> have turned the role down. After Walter turned me down I offered the
> same role to John Billingsley, Dr. Phlox on Star Trek Enterprise. **John
> was even more offended by the libertarian content of Alongside Night
> than Walter**—especially with my choice to have the specific agency of
> the federal government that acts as the antagonists be FEMA, the bête
> noire of conspiracists and Tea Party types alike. In the original 1979
> novel it was the FBI and I changed it because it made sense to me that
> in the economic collapse I portray in the movie the agency that would
> naturally take point for the federal government would be the one with
> "Emergency Management" in its name. I made John an offer that if he
> took the role we could tour the movie to college campuses and after
> each showing he and I could debate the issues. I thought that would be
> fun. It wasn't enough to convince John that I wasn't making a Tea
> Party propaganda movie though and I next offered the role to Ethan
> Keogh—Agent Jack Goldwater in Lady Magdalene's—who took the role and
> killed it. There is still a Trek connection, though, because like me
> Ethan is also an out-of-the-closet Trekkie.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Fannish Interview with Alongside Night author/filmmaker, J. Neil Schulman](http://www.ncc-1776.org/tle2014/tle761-20140309-04.html)</sup></sub>

It's hard to believe that two actors as savvy as Russ and Wang would take part in a film of this nature without tacitly supporting its goals although it's noteworthy that neither were present for the film's premiere, nor any of the film tours, nor any of the Q&A sessions that Sorbo and Schulman held after each showing.